# Makefile:149: recipe for target 'all' failed make: *** [all] Error 2

Tags: cmake, root-framework

I am trying to install root-cern to and then install Geant4 
I get this massage and I do not understand what is the problem and how to fix it. The message is:

```
CMake Error at /home/user/root/build-dir/AFTERIMAGE-prefix/src/AFTERIMAGE-stamp/AFTERIMAGE-configure-RelWithDebInfo.cmake:16 (message):
  Command failed: Permission denied

   './configure' '--prefix' '/home/user/root/build-dir' '--libdir=/home/ola/root/build-dir/lib' '--with-ttf' '--with-afterbase=no' '--without-svg' '--disable-glx' '--with-builtin-ungif' '--with-jpeg' '--with-jpeg-includes=/usr/include' '--with-png' '--with-png-includes=/usr/include' '--with-tiff-includes=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu' 'CC=/usr/bin/cc' 'CFLAGS='

  See also

    /home/user/root/build-dir/AFTERIMAGE-prefix/src/AFTERIMAGE-stamp/AFTERIMAGE-configure-*.log


CMakeFiles/AFTERIMAGE.dir/build.make:105: recipe for target 'AFTERIMAGE-prefix/src/AFTERIMAGE-stamp/AFTERIMAGE-configure' failed
make[2]: *** [AFTERIMAGE-prefix/src/AFTERIMAGE-stamp/AFTERIMAGE-configure] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:163: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/AFTERIMAGE.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/AFTERIMAGE.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:149: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: The error is: "Command failed: Permission denied". Message "recipe for target 'all' failed" is its result.

Comment: may i ask how to solve this "permission denied"

Comment: Yes, you may. I just noted that you use *non-primary* error message in the title, so it have a little sence.